# Is the empty result message of a ValueHelpDialog customizable somehow?

Tags: sapui5

I have to customize the empty result message of a search result of a ValueHelpDialog. Is this possible somehow?
[image: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.71.14/?sap-language=en#/entity/sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.valuehelpdialog.filterbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try fetching the table control via `getTableAsync` from the value help dialog:

```js
this._oValueHelpDialog.getTableAsync().then(function (oTable) {
  oTable.setNoData("No Data text"); // sap.ui.table.Table
});
```

[API reference: `sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog#getTableAsync`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog%23methods/getTableAsync)